# Sp.Js Error When Running CAML Queries

Tags: javascript, development, caml, sp.js, script-webpart

I have added the below code to a (non-Publishing feature enabled) page in SPO to grab some items from another list and render them out; have done this sort of thing before without an issue (code is being reused from one such instance).

JSLink parts at the top can be ignored - these are rendering the links required fine.

Based on the debug alert() calls I added in, the code is executing at least as far as the listEnum loop inside getCamlPass(), but after that alert is triggered I get the following error in the console:

[image]

Have tried recreating the page to no avail, same error. Finding it very hard from the error to determine where the problem lies, but I can't see any errors with my JS code - all the variables have been declared as globals just to avoid any scope problems in the first run.

Code below - any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Declare global variables
var clientContext;
var oWeb;
var oList;
var allItems;
var camlQuery;
var camlQueryString;
var listEnum;
var currentItem;
var thisCurrentId;
var thisCurrentName;
var markupBlock = "<b>Related Minute Documents</b><br />";

// Load this function AFTER the meetings list so the column is available for editing
(function () {
    // Create an object that has the context information about the fields that we want to change the rendering of.
    var mlContext = {};
    mlContext.Templates = {};
    mlContext.Templates.Fields = {
        // Apply the new rendering for these fields on List View  - note the Static Name must be used
        "minutesLink": { "View": mlMarkup }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(mlContext);
})();

// This function provides the rendering logic for the list view
function mlMarkup(ctx) {
    // Construct the markup block to pass to the function inserted at the top of the page
    var jslMarkupBlock = "<a href='javascript:showMinutes(\"";
    jslMarkupBlock += ctx.CurrentItem.meetingTitle;
    jslMarkupBlock += "\")';'>Click me</a>";
    return jslMarkupBlock;
}

// Async fail for getting the initial list info
function getListFail() {
    alert("Failed to get list.");
}

// Async fail for running the CAML query
function getCamlFail() {
    alert("Failed to issue CAML query.");
}

// Async success for getting the initial list info
function getListPass(meetingTitle) {
    alert("Passed value: "+meetingTitle);
    alert("Building CAML query...");
    camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQueryString = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"fkMeetingTitle\" /><Value Type=\"Lookup\">";
    camlQueryString += meetingTitle;
    camlQueryString += "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(camlQueryString);
    allItems = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(allItems);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(getCamlPass,getCamlFail);
}

// Async success for running the CAML query
function getCamlPass() {
  alert("Parsing query result...");
  listEnum = allItems.getEnumerator();
  while (listEnum.moveNext()) {
      alert("Enumerating items...");
      currentItem = listEnum.get_current();
      thisCurrentId = currentItem.get_item('ID');
      thisCurrentName = currentItem.get_item('Name');
      markupBlock += thisCurrentName;
      markupBlock += "<br />";
      document.getElementById('relatedMinutes').innerHTML = markupBlock;
    }
}

// Click function for links rendered by JSL
function showMinutes(meetingTitle) {
  alert("Meeting: "+meetingTitle);
  // Run the initial query to get the list
  alert("Opening client context...");
  clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
  oWeb =  clientContext.get_web();
  oList = oWeb.get_lists().getByTitle("Meeting Minutes");
  clientContext.load(oList);
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(getListPass(meetingTitle),getListFail);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your are trying to get items from a library, and you are trying to get the name:

```
thisCurrentName = currentItem.get_item('Name');
```

The internal name of that column is not `Name` , you could try `FileLeafRef`

Comment: D'oh! Schoolboy error, I assumed the static and display names would be the same. Should've checked the SPCamlQueryHelper schemata output first.